# Laravel Reset Password Button by Email Cannot Be Clicked

Tags: laravel, reset-password

Trying to make reset password, but the problem is reset password button cannot be clicked

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $link = url("/password/reset/".$this->token);

        return ( new MailMessage )
            ->from('test@example.com')
            ->subject( 'Reset your password' )
            ->line( "You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account. " )
            ->action('Reset Password', $link)
            ->line( 'This password reset link will expire in 60 minutes. If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.

            Regards,
            Laravel' );
    }
```

Comment: I think you are trying to say that, you have recieved the email from user end. But The button click is not triggering anything. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes. You're right... Any solution?

Comment: You are using the `url` helper twice on the link so the result of that looks something like that: `http://localhost/http://localhost/password/reset/?token=...` Maybe that's causing the button to be not clickable.

Comment: Trying to change like this `action('reset password, $link)`. Still not working

Comment: are your using any custom template for your email ?

Comment: @JunaedSiam: Yes I did!

Comment: Make sure to use the <a> HTML element, not the <button> element. <button> element needs Javascript to trigger. Hope that helps !

Comment: The code lays here `$link = url("/password/reset/".$this->token);`, how can I put the `<a>`?. Take a look at the tutorial, there is no `<a>`. https://thewebtier.com/laravel/modify-password-reset-email-text-laravel/